# Pause during cutscenes

Tags: pc, steam, grand-theft-auto-iv

Is it possible to pause GTA IV (PC version, via Steam) during cutscenes? And if so, how?

Answer (score 5):

**Sometimes**, hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> during cutscenes will pause the game - hitting it again will un-pause it. The sound is correctly paused and resumed as well, even mid-sentence.

Unfortunately, this doesn't always work.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, if you have patch 1.0.4.0 (Title Update 2) or above, the cutscenes pause if you <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> out of the game.

According to the changelog from [this link](http://www.filepulse.com/patches/Grand_Theft_Auto_4_Patch_1-0-4-0.shtml#). (click on "Click Here To Show More Patch Details").

Comment: I tried it and when alt-tabbing back the sound continued precisely from the moment I left, so that sounds about right - unfortunately, the video didn't come back at all, so I was left with a blank screen and had to forcefully shutdown.

Comment: I... don't know what to say. What GPU are you on?

Comment: GTS 250. I'll give it another go later, since that does sound promising.

Comment: That's weird, I thought it might have something to do with your graphics card, but googling hasn't revealed anything... Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

[Universal Pause Button](https://github.com/ryanries/UniversalPauseButton/releases) can be used, the program freezes the game process. Hotkey can be modified.
Please note that a paused program can't recover if the foreground window is changed - "unpause" first.